# Using the binded object C#/XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to XAML, and maybe my question is a little bit stupid, but, here is my problem.

I have a `ListView`, and i have set the `ItemSource` to a ObservableList inside a ModelView class

Here's how my code looks like:

```
public class ListModelView
{
    ObservableList<MyClass> _list = new ObservableList<MyClass>();
    public ObservableList<MyClass> MyList { get{return _list;} set{}}

    public ListModelView()
    {
        _list = methodThatReturnsAListFromAWebService;
    }
}
```

Every thing works just fine. But how do I modify (add, delete) elements from `MyList`. To get it work i've modified properties as `static`, and it work. But i wonder if this is the right way to do it. Thank You.

Comment: You will need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` to your `ListModelView` class to get the XAML to update when the list does.

Comment: it does update without that, if the _list & MyList are set to static

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access it by giving your view model in XAML, like this:

```
<viewModel:YourViewModel x:Name="ViewModelName"/>
```

Now you'll be able to access it in the code behind.
For further reading i'd recommend `Messenger` from MVVM light toolkit, you can communicate between your View Models using this class

Answer (score 0):

Your MyList Set Property is empty.

```
public ObservableList<MyClass> MyList { get{return _list;} set{ _list=value;}}
```

Now you will be allowed to edit delete and add items to MyList

Comment: i can add them without that inside my class. But how i do outside?

Comment: you have to create the object of the class and and then call the property outsid. eg: var ListModelViewObj = new ListModelView();
then ListModelViewObj.MyList will allow you to edit outside the class